# Access .net web service in localhost from android device

Tags: .net, android, web-services, localhost

I have problem accessing my .net web service in my laptop localhost from Android device.

I can access it perfectly from Android Emulator using address 10.0.2.2:49654.

Then, I created Access Point using connectify from my laptop to share its local area connection and I was able to connect the Android device to the Access Point via wifi.

Then, I tried to use the same address, 10.0.2.2:49654, but failed.

I used my laptop ip address, 192.168.1.100, but still failed.

I tried other option, 192.168.1.100:49654, but again, failed.

I appreciate any help given for me, thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You just might be looking at the wrong IP. Your 'local' IP is 192.168.**1**.xx usually, but Connectify IP is (at least for me) 192.168.**2**.xx

go cmd -> ipconfig and get the other IP from there. These are mine

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d15d:982b:df0e:7df5%40
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1 - Connectify local ip
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local.lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4962:1644:5e18:408c%38
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2 - local ip -> wifi to internet
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I think i don't have the second ip address. When i did ipconfig, only one ip address that comes out, that is 192.168.2.1. And 192.168.1.100 will also shown if i connect my laptop with internet cable. So, i think I don't know my local ip address..

Comment: I got media state disconnected for wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection. any clue? thanks

Comment: @Fella, I'm assuming you're using Windows 7, if not your problem may be just that. Put internet cable back in your laptop, use Local Area Connection for Internet and start Hotspot. Connect phone to wireless, and try if internet works (browser). If it doesn't restart Connectify and maybe pc and try again, it's known to be glitchy. You said that without cable you only get one ip, that's 192.168.2.1. That is the ip that you should use on your phone, since this ip is your local IP for wireless network. The other one is for cable connection, which does not interest you. Let me know how it works out

Comment: The IP that I get is `192.168.55.1`, I used it put doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

see the android docs http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the hosts file in your device with Hosts Editor

Answer (score -1):

1) Try to open the port from your router and use 192.168.1.100

if failed

2) Try to open the port from your router and use your [public IP Address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Comment: use 192.168.1.100 without :49654 or still i should use 102.168.1.100:49654? thanks